# Get working Wordpress and Magento together

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, url, url-rewriting

Here's the problem :

I have a wordpress project which will be the front site (so http://my-site.com/ need point to the wordpress index.php) then magento must be accessible with http://my-site.com/shop/ which point to the magento index.php.

I can't figure out how to write the .htaccess and vhost file.

In my previous attempt, wordpress seems to handle all the route and throws a 404 if i go to /shop/

Thank you.

Comment: Don't tell me you mixed 2 software's source code in same folder ...

Comment: No its on separate folder, i have a magento directory inside the wordpress directory

Comment: That's NOT separate. Your magento is affected by WordPress `.htaccess`. You should put them in parallel folders.

Answer (score 0):

you can add in your wordpress .htaccess file as below

```
## 301 Redirect Entire Directory

RedirectMatch 301 

http://my-site.com/shop(.*)

http://my-site.com/shop/index.php/$1
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @Rpg600,it is wokring at my end.if my answer is useful to you.i would be glad if you will vote up my answer and accept it. so some on can use if future if they have same like above requirement.